# Add +1 to cell in same row but different column from Vlooked-up item

Tags: vba, excel

I'm quite new to VBA so I apologise in advance for coding mistakes ;)

What I'd like my code to do is:

1. Take the caption from a label on the form
2. Lookup that alphanumerical caption on the workbook’s sheet
3. Add +1 to a number which is on the same row of the Vlook part but on a **different column**.

   ```
   Private Sub submitButton_Click()
   'Declaring variables that will be used to Vlookup on the top level part number list

   Dim passPartNo1form As String
   Dim passPartNo1workbook As String
   Dim failPartNo1workbook As String
   Dim rowPass1 As Integer

   Sheets("Sheet5").Activate

   'If Pass checkbox is selected
   If pass1.Value = True Then

       'Assign variable passPartNo1form to the caption of the PartNumber1 label
       passPartNo1form = partNumber1.Caption

       'Look up the risk score in the Top Level list
       passPartNo1workbook = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(passPartNo1form, Range("TopLevelList"), 3, False)

       'This should define the row of the code that has been V looked up
       rowPass1 = passPartNo1workbook.Row

       'Add +1 to the number in column 3, and row the same as the part which has been V looked up
       Cells(rowPass1, 3).Value = Cells(2, 3).Value + 1

   End If

   End Sub
   ```

I’ve been trying to get my head round this for ages but I always get a “Invalid qualifier” error. Any suggestion would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: There is nothing like `Sheet5.Activate`. You probably need `Sheets("Sheet5").Activate`.

Comment: What line is highlighted on the error?

Comment: @EganWolf: no worries; if one of his sheets has the code name Sheet5 then it can be accessed like that perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your passPartNo1workbook is Dim'ed as a String; you cannot take a .Row from it.  I assume you want to get the row at which the value from the VLookup function is found?  In that case you need the .Match function.

Comment: Or keep it a string and use sheets(passPartNo1workbook)